# Python pygame.midi error portmidi

Tags: python, pygame, midi

I use Debian 8 with any version of python pygame
When i try to ear a midi by just clicking i got :

```
Une erreur est survenue
La lecture de ce film exige un greffon Décodeur audio/x-midi-event qui n'est pas installé.
```

But i can ear it with :

```
aplay monfichier.mid
```

If I try to run my prog python/pygame a well know example find on the web that im sure it works :

```
import pygame
import time
import pygame.midi

pygame.midi.init()
player= pygame.midi.Output(0)
player.set_instrument(48,1)

major=[0,4,7,12]

def go(note):
    player.note_on(note, 127,1)
    time.sleep(1)
    player.note_off(note,127,1)

def arp(base,ints):
    for n in ints:
        go(base+n)

def chord(base, ints):
    player.note_on(base,127,1)
    player.note_on(base+ints[1],127,1)
    player.note_on(base+ints[2],127,1)
    player.note_on(base+ints[3],127,1)
    time.sleep(1)
    player.note_off(base,127,1)
    player.note_off(base+ints[1],127,1)
    player.note_off(base+ints[2],127,1)
    player.note_off(base+ints[3],127,1)
def end():
       pygame.quit()
```

I have:

```
python3 pygameex.py 
Exception ignored in: <pypm.Output object at 0xb6514e30>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pypm.pyx", line 306, in pypm.Output.__dealloc__ (src/pypm.c:1438)
Exception: b"PortMidi: `Bad pointer'"
```

I tried python 2.7 and python 3 almost same error
I looked for it on the web and i just found the same question without answers

I want to make notes and chords without passing by files
I'm looking for python module but cannot find happyness

Comment: `aplay` or `aplaymidi`?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone would experience the same issue, it usually happens when you forget to close the midi resources properly at the end of your program :

```
import pygame.midi
import time

pygame.midi.init()

midiOut = pygame.midi.Output(0)
midiOut.note_on(64,127)
time.sleep(0.5)
midiOut.note_off(64,127)

midiOut.close()
```